# Connect to postgreSQL and render using node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I try to connect to postgreSQL database and display the results in my html file.
I use node-postgres module version ^7.7.1

My code is:

```
const express = require('express');
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg');
const pg = require('pg');

const config = {
  user: 'username',
  database: 'db_name',
  password: 'userpass',
  port: 3000
};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  const pool = new pg.Pool(config)
  const client = new pg.Client(connect);
  // connection using created pool
  pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM example_table')
    res.render('index')
    done()
  })
  pool.end()
});
```

I'm getting error: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined.
What's the proper way to connect to database and render the result ?

Comment: If `client` is undefined, it's likely that the connection pool experienced an error trying to retrieve one. Does `err` contain any useful information?

Comment: This is unrelated, but also: you are creating and closing a new connection pool for each request. Typically, you would only want to create one connection pool for your application, then query from the pool.

Comment: So the ```pool``` needs to be outside the ```app.get()``` ?

Comment: I'd suggest that, yes. It doesn't really resolve the problem you asked about, but it should help with application performance to re-use connections from the same pool rather than making multiple pools and using a single connection from each.